# spliting java string and adding characters at end and start of of alphanumeric

Tags: java

I want to add a character at end and start of aplhanumeric in a string(max 8 characters). Any example will be great help to me in java

```
String S1 = "xnXrmXWBidhksyn70rGyTH==QNujyRMdrQi8dO9X+RunER==LTy+K
mGI+KRCcRtmP5ehfR==";
```

I will add `a,b,c,d,e,f,g and h` at every end and start of aplhanumeric in above string and I want output as

```
 xnXrmXWBidhksyn70rGyTHa==bQNujyRMdrQi8dO9Xc+dRunERe==fLTyg+hK
mGI+KRCcRtmP5ehfR==
```

Please note that the string I will get will be dynamic and contains the non alphanumberic characters anywhere in the string.

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a homework question, and we're not going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

`String [] splits = S1.split("\\p{Punct}{1,}");`
and then iterate over array and add what you want to the end

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but the string may contain any nonalphanumeric and also it may be any number of chars like === or == or = or %%% or ^^^^^^ or * etc etc

Comment: maks, thanks for your help. I got the solution in different way

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not explained well and your output is not following any pattern.Still according to what I did understand u can split string on index of first `non-alphnumeric` charcter and next `alphnumeric` character until eof string.And then add whatever u want at the start and end of subString.Something like

```
    int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
    int index = 0 , tempIndex = 0;
    char ch1 = json.charAt(index);
    while (startIndex == 0) {
                if (!Character.isLetter(ch1)) {
                    startIndex = index;
                } else {
                    index++;
                    ch1 = S1.charAt(index);
                }
            }
     while (endIndex == 0) {
                if (Character.isLetter(ch1)) {
                    endIndex = index;
                } else {
                    index++;


                    ch1 = S1.charAt(index);
                    }
                }

   S1 = S1.substring(tempIndex, startIndex) + "a" + S1.substring(startIndex, endIndex) 

+"b"+S1.substring(endIndex, S1.length);
tempIndex = index;
```

Now continue with index andtempIndex untill eof string .

Comment: thanks for your reply and I agree with you that it is not following any pattern. As per as my requirement is considered, I want to add a letter before and after a bunch of non alphanumeric characters. 

xnXrmXWBidhksyn70rGyTH==bQNujyRMdrQi8dO9X+RunER==LTy+K
mGI+KRCcRtmP5ehfR==


In the above example I want to add a before first bunch of non alphanumeric characters and b at end of first bunch of non alphanumeric characters(in above example ==) and then c,d for next bunch of non alpha characters (in above +) etc etc

Comment: Ok..Then your job is done.You just have to make some changes in above code according to your requirement.Like you first have to split on non-alphanumeric keywords and then concat again inserting your keyWordds.This will definetly work.

Comment: I have done some changes in above code as your requirement.That is not your exact solution but approx.May be that will help u.